# python: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by python) from specific dir, but not from a copy of it

Tags: apt, python

I have 2 repositories. In both I'm running a similar command (in Python's `multiprocess`, with 2 seconds sleep between).

The command is a python script I have, and I'm running it via each repo's virtualenv (created with python3.5)

How is it one repo gives this error and the other does not? I tried reproducing without `multiprocessing` and it does reproduce. One repo is flawed somehow in its libc6 search.

I pre-installed `sudo apt install libc6-dev libc6-dbg libc6-amd64`

Comment: What OS/release are you running?  Python 3.5 implies Xenial (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3), but no supported Ubuntu uses `glibc` 2.25  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=glibc)

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu. (18.04)